# Conflito RewriteRule no htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

Já fiz várias pesquisas mas não achei a solução do meu problema.

Tenho um htaccess no seguinte formato:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule fotos$ arc_fotos.php
RewriteRule fotos/$ arc_fotos.php
RewriteRule minha-area/$ arc_minha_area.php
RewriteRule minha-area/fotos$ arc_minhas-fotos.php
```

Quando eu acesso o endereço meudominio.com.br/fotos -> página de fotos (arc_fotos) OK

Mas quando eu acesso o endereço meudominio.com.br/minha-area/fotos ele vai para arc_fotos.php sendo que eu quero que vá para arc_minhas_fotos.php

O mesmo caso acontece quando:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule blog/$ arc_blog.php
RewriteRule esqueci esqueci_senha.php
```

Quando o usuário acessa meudominio.com.br/blog/uma-pagina-com-url-in**esqueci**vel ele interpreta in**ESQUECI**vel e vai para a página esquece_senha.php

Alguém pode me auxiliar para evitar esse tipo de conflito?

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver seu problema, você deve saber analisar o nível de especificação das suas regras.

> **As regras mais especificas devem ficar no topo.**

#### Mas como assim nível de especificação?

O nível de especificação pode ser verificado de varias formar (se quiser saber mais peça depois, vou abordar apenas o seu caso)

> Para saber se algo é mais especifico basta verificar se alguma outra regra engloba ela.

```
RewriteRule fotos$ arc_fotos.php # menos especifico
RewriteRule minha-area/fotos$ arc_minhas-fotos.php # mais especifico
```

A primeira regra engloba a segunda pois `fotos$` também captura as sentença de `minha-area/fotos$` ou seja a primeira regra é mais genérica tornando a segunda mais especifica, já que para a segunda ocorrer é necessário ter junto `minha-area`.

Seguindo a norma citada a cima a sua ordem então deveria ser :

```
RewriteRule minha-area/fotos$ arc_minhas-fotos.php # mais especifico
RewriteRule fotos$ arc_fotos.php # menos especifico
```