# Problemas com rewriterule no htaccess URL similares

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Tenho duas URLS

http://localhost/odata/entre-em-contato

http://localhost/odata/en

Elas são URL diferentes que levam para arquivos .php diferentes, então fiz assim meu htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^entre-em-contato entre-em-contato.php
RewriteRule ^en antigo-en.php
```

Mas ambas as URLs estão levando para o arquivo `antigo-en.php`

Tentei inverter como li nesse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230805/conflito-rewriterule-no-htaccess):

```
RewriteRule ^en antigo-en.php
RewriteRule ^entre-em-contato entre-em-contato.php
```

Mas continua ambas redirecionando para `antigo-en.php`

O que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua regra não está correta, você deveria demarcar o início usando o carácter **(^)** e o fim da expressão **($)** como abaixo:

```
RewriteRule ^odata/entre-em-contato$ entre-em-contato.php [L]
```

A expressão acima traduzindo em linhas gerais diz, que a url que contiver após o domínio que no seu caso é **localhost**, **odata** precedido de **entre-em-contato** séra encaminhada para o arquivo na raiz **entre-em-contato.php**

```
RewriteRule ^odata/en$               antigo-en.php        [L]
```

A url que contiver **odata** precedido de **en** será encaminhada para o arquivo na raiz **antigo-en.php**

O [L] é last ou seja, em uma lista de condições, não serão lidas as condições abaixo das que estiver com esta flag.